# Error while animating element in SVG

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, raphael

I have to make an animation frame by frame the problem that there are many elements and I never did anything like that, however I have a problem or conflict that he want the element to be excited for the third frame "that moves" put it this impress stopped on screen might be giving some conflict of something, someone would know their identity?

```
// Second Frame with group Paths = Symbol_9_frame2
// Third Frame with group Paths = Symbol_9_frame3

  // Error or Conflict Animate 
  Symbol_9_frame2.animate(Symbol_9_frame3);
```

[Fiddle and Fullcode](http://jsfiddle.net/K856b/2/)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are wanting to do here. I think you aren't using the animate properly...can you rephrase exactly what you want to happen on frame 2 and frame 3 ?

Comment: Hi, need to change the set of paths of the frame 2 for what is in frame 3 with effect. updated the fiddle for you to understand better http://jsfiddle.net/K856b/4/ thanks.

Comment: Why not just do something like http://jsfiddle.net/K856b/5/